# Cannot open older .xcodeproj file in XCode 4.3.2

Tags: xcode, xcode4.3

I just upgraded XCode to 4.3.2 and tried to load a project I am working on - in the past I simply used the "Open" menu and then pointed to the PROJECT.xcodeproj file (which is in fact a directory) - which then caused XCode to open the project. However when I do this now, I get an alert box stating that "The document PROJECT.xcodeproj" could not be opened.

Anyone else experiencing this? Any ideas what could be wrong or where to look for clues?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I got this error when using file->open from within Xcode.  But I got a different error when double clicking the Name.xcodeproj file.  It was:

```
Cannot open "Name.xcodeproj" because it is already open in another workspace.
```

Exiting Xcode completely and then double-clicking the .xcodeproj file to open the project and Xcode simultaneously solved it for me =)

Comment: "Amazingly" is right.  I don't know how xcode can still have so many show-stopping bugs... even now at version 4.3.3!</rant>

Comment: There's this bug in 4.6 yet, and this solution has worked perfectly for me.
PS: First minutes using Mac OS in my life...I have to say this error and its solution is not the UX I was expecting...

Answer (score 3):

I originally had Xcode projects on 4.3.2 and wanted to transfer the files to a new macbook I just bought and installed Xcode on.  For those people saying that just transferring the files over and starting it up will work, it didn't for me as the Xcode that installed on the my new macbook as 4.3.3  I would get the error window pop-up saying 'could not open **__**.xcodeproj' without any further explanation.

What did work for me was upgrading the 4.3.2 Xcode on the old mac to 4.3.3, THEN transferring the files over to the new macbook (that already had 4.3.3).  Then no issues.

Answer (score 1):

I just started to experience that myself. I did a reboot of the machine and retried and it worked. I might also try a log out login too.

Answer (score 0):

Exit Xcode completely and then double-click the .xcodeproj file you want to open.